# Passing variables to fmax

Tags: c, variables, math.h

So I have the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
int main (void) {
float max = fmax (1.0,2.0);
return 0;
}
```

Which compiles and runs fine, but if instead of passing 1.0 and 2.0 to the function I pass a, b with those values:

```
#include <math.h>
int main (void) {
float a = 1.0; float b = 2.0;
float max = fmax (a,b);
return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `fmax'
```

What is the diffrence? What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using this command to compile:

```
c99 fmax_test.c
```

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but note that `fmax` is for `double`s - you should be using `fmaxf` for `float`s.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same results using fmaxf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case `fmax` probably gets optimised away at compile time. In the second case it does not and you then get a link error. Without knowing what compiler you are using it's hard to give a specific remedy, but if it's gcc then you may need to add `-lm`, e.g.

```
c99 -Wall fmax_test.c -lm
```

Note also that `fmax` is for `double`s - you should be using `fmaxf` for `float`s.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using gcc.

Comment: If he is using gcc for both the cases, how can the first case get optimized out if fmax function is found in an external library ?

Comment: @VivekS: in the first case `fmax(1.0, 2.0)` can be evaluated at compile time and just replaced with 2.0, so there is no function call to `fmax` when the code is linked.

Comment: @Paul R I get the following warning when I use fmax(1.0, 2.0) - "warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘fmax’ " - This means, fmax is a gcc built-in function ? If it is not built into gcc, then how can gcc evaluate the result ? If it is a built-in function, then why does it need to link with math library in the second case ?

Comment: @VivekS: you probably forgot to `#include <math.h>` ?

Comment: @VivekS optimization is done at compile time.-lm works in link time.I guess. use "c99 -Wall -c fmax_test.c" to compile can generate obj file.

Comment: @Paul R Yeah, #include <math.h> removed the error. But where is gcc finding the definition of fmax in the first case ?

Comment: It is not clear from the header file math.h, how the compiler knows to optimize fmax.

Comment: gcc recognises [a number of standard C library functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) and it can often evaluate these at compile-time or generate inline code for run-time rather than treating these as normal library function calls. You can disable this behaviour and force library functions to be called by specifying `-fno-builtins`.

Answer (score 2):

compile with -lm
i'm using gcc. maybe not OK with your compiler.

try this:

```
c99 fmax_test.c -lm
```